# How do you change the display format of floats & doubles in Xcode debug window?

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, llvm, lldb

Im debugging C in Xcode and setting breakpoints in functions to examine the value of various doubles. Xcode insists on displaying them using scientific notation, which is a real pain. I need to see a decimal representation. The right click "View Value" menu option of *Decimal*, does weird things. Anyone have any idea how to get this to play nice short of printf'n everything I want to see??

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the [LLDB Variable Formatting](http://lldb.llvm.org/varformats.html) documentation, specifically the *Type Format* section near the top.

You can use the `type format` command to change the default output.

From the link above

> Type formats enable you to quickly override the default format for
>   displaying primitive types (the usual basic C/C++/ObjC types: int,
>   float, char, ...).
>
> If for some reason you want all int variables in your program to print
>   out as hex, you can add a format to the int type.
>
> This is done by typing
>
> (lldb) type format add --format hex int

To change the default display of your jDate objects you should be able to do something like

```
type format add -f float jDate
```

You can get more info from the debugger itself with `help <format>` but the above linked page reads quite well.

If that doesn't solve your problem, you may need to read further down on *Type Summaries*. I can't remember what Xcode displays, be it the format or the summary.

Additionally, the WWDC2012 session **# 415 "Debugging with LLDB"** shows methods to change these display formats and add your own. The relevant bits are around the 35 minute mark, but the whole session is great.

Hope that helps!

Comment: The `LLDB Variable Formatting` doesn't say anything about escaping characters. `{$VAR.year} {$VAR.month}`  shows up as `Summary Unavailable`, but `{$VAR.year}-{$VAR.month}` works. Also, `{$VAR.year}:{$VAR.month}` gives the error `Summary format is not valid`, but escaping them like `\ ` or `\:` gets rid of the errors, but it shows up exactly like that, including the slash.