# lldb - How to display float with decimals using "type format add"

Tags: format, lldb

I have a variable of type float.  Xcode displays it using scientific notation (i.e. 3.37626e+07).  I'm trying to get it to display using dot notation (i.e. 33762616.00).
I've tried every format provided by lldb, but none displays the float using decimals.  I read other posts and watched the WWDC2012 session 415 ([as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488028/how-do-you-change-the-display-format-of-xcode-debug-windows-display-of-local-var)), but I must be too close the forest to see the trees.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a custom data formatter in your `~/.lldbinit` file for type `float`.  e.g.

```
Process 13204 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0xb6f8d, 0x0000000100000f33 a.out`main + 35 at a.c:5, stop reason = step over
    #0: 0x0000000100000f33 a.out`main + 35 at a.c:5
   2    int main ()
   3    {
   4        float f = 33762616.0;
-> 5        printf ("%f\n", f);
   6    }
(lldb) p f
(float) $0 = 3.37626e+07
(lldb) type summ add -v -o "return '%f' % valobj.GetData().GetFloat(lldb.SBError(), 0)" float
(lldb) p f
(float) $1 = 33762616.000000
(lldb)
```

The default set of formatters provided by lldb can't do this, but dropping into Python allows you a lot of flexibility.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know you could use Python like that.  Good stuff!