# How do I make the Xcode debugger show uint8_t values as numbers?

Tags: xcode, debugging, uint8t

The Xcode debugger expression window shows `uint8_t` values as their char equivalents.

[image]

So here `m_interlace_delay` is 0, `m_column` is 48, `m_row` is 10 and `m_raster` is 10.

What can I do to make Xcode display these values as numbers? I am happy for `char` values to be shown as chars, but for `uint8_t` I'm finding it rather inconvenient.

Individual values can be cast to `unsigned` or something, by adding new expression by hand, but this doesn't work for structs or arrays.

(Xcode Version 10.1 (10B61), debugging a Mac program.)

Comment: short answer: in the lldb prompt type `type format add -f decimal uint8_t`

answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11751074/1911863  The Reference: 
http://lldb.llvm.org/varformats.html