How do I show a u8 as a number in VSCode?
When debugging on VSCode, the Watch panel shows u8 variables as chars. In most instances this is not informative at all. What can I change to make u8 appear as a number ?

What debugger/toolchain are you using?

Can reproduce on VSCode, rust-analyzer and CodeLLDB.

Might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72129333/lldb-prints-i8-as-signed-char
